# Javascript: How to check if check_box in rails is checked or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a check_box with id "current" in one of my views on my Rail application and I also have a text_field with id "end"  in the same view. When the checkbox is clicked, I want the display of the text_field to be none.

I had a jQuery method which was not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if ($('#current').checked) {
      $("#end").show();
   }
   else {
      $("#end").hide();
   }
}
);
```

Anyway I can check the Boolean value of the check_box using Javascript?

Comment: `if ($('#current').is(":checked") {` try

Comment: `$('#current')` returns a jQuery object... so there is no checked property

Comment: Or you can simplify it to `$("#end").toggle($('#current').is(":checked"));`

Comment: I'd suggest checking the `checked` property of the `input` element directly. Using the `is(":checked")` query isn't necessary and adds unnecessary cycles. Please see link for demonstration http://codepen.io/richseviora/pen/MaXGWz.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if ($('#current').is(":checked")) {
      $("#end").show();
   }
   else {
      $("#end").hide();
   }
}
);
```

Try using [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

> Description: Matches all elements that are checked or selected.